# why unnable to do annotation adjacent to legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to add text to a location that is adjacent to the legend. Here is what I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = y = [1,2,3,4,5]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
leg = ax.legend(['line 1'], loc=6, frameon=False)
plt.draw()
p = leg.get_window_extent()
ax.annotate('Annotation Text', (p.p0[0], p.p1[1]), (p.p0[0], p.p1[1]), 
        xycoords='figure pixels', zorder=9)
plt.show()
```

This is exactly the script contained in the stackoverflow question at [Get Matplotlib legend location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711376/get-matplotlib-legend-location). When I run the exact same script I produce different results. When I run this script the string "Annotation Text" appears at the bottom left of the figure.

For the record, the value of p when I run this script is `Bbox(x0=0.0, y0=0.0, x1=1.0, y1=1.0)`.

How can I obtain the coordinates of the Legend, preferably in terms of axes coordinates ie. ax.transAxes ?

I am using matplotlib 1.5.0 and python 2.7

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening here... It looks like coordinates are not set until plt.show() happens... I printed the leg.window_extent() after plt.show() and they are correct there.... Why not using the set_title() method for legend? leg.set_title("Annotation Text")

Comment: The reason for not using the set_title() method is because ultimately I want to place annotation outside the legend; and said annotation is to be quite independent and disjoint from the legend. I am trying to achieve a precise layout for the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inverse_transformed` to convert figure pixels to axes fraction:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = y = [1,2,3,4,5]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

leg = ax.legend(['line 1'], loc=6, frameon=False)

fig.canvas.draw()

p = leg.get_window_extent().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)

ax.annotate('Annotation Text', (p.p0[0], p.p1[1]), xycoords='axes fraction')
```

This will produce plot like this:

[image]

I also use matplotlib 1.5.0 and python 2.7 and I always get the same plot regardless of how many times the script is executed.

Comment: Thank you Primer. Now I know to use fig.canvas.draw() instead of plt.draw().